# torch.save(predictions, predictions_path, pickle_module=dill) system dead

Tags: system, torch

I trained the whole network and got the parameters. When I use one pth to infer the result on a test dataset, just testing, by debugging, each time when it goes to "torch.save(predictions, predictions_path, pickle_module=dill) ", the whole system gets dead. The clock stops and the mouse cannot move. Push contl+alt+F1 to tty but no response. Nothing can do. Everything is dead. If I restart the machine by the "start" button, the system then says "lost inducing document" and the whole system dumped and I have to re-install the whole Linux. If I wait for the dead system to be back, it costs one day or so, and finally, it gets back to response and just shows "system error".

I searched for all possible solutions and tried but not work. I bought new memory banks, updated and upgraded all software, checked error logs, and optimized many system services. But all is useless. Each time it got dead for one day. The system is centos for ubuntu. Anyone can help?

Comment: pycharm says: "process finished with exit code 137 interrupted by signal 9 sigkill"

Comment: pycharm says: "process finished with exit code 137 interrupted by signal 9 sigkill"    and log said "out of memory kill process score 716 or sacrifice child" but there are 15 G of free space   and log kernel said "oom_reaper:reaped process python, now anon-rss, file-rss, shmem-rss, total-vm:33774904kb, anon-rss:18257004kb, file-rss:98164kb, shmem-rss:12292kb"

Comment: syslog: nautilus:8313 Gtk-CRITICAL: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child:assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER(revealer)' failed      GLib-GObject-CRITICAL g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE(instance)' failed

Comment: RAM 24 G    Disk space 15 G

Comment: org. gnome.Nautilus1797 nautilus 8313 GLib-GObject-warning invalid pointer instance     gnome-shell invoked oom-killer:gfp_mask=0x14200ca, gnome-shell, 4.15.0-117-generic #118~16.04.1-Ubuntu, Dell Precision workstation t3500, a15, dump_stack+0x6d/0x8e, dump_header+0x77/0x285, oom_kill_process, outofmemory, free:41370, free_pcp:0, free_cma:0